# Plotting bar plots right from dplyr

Tags: ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to ask how to handle ouptut from dplyr and then plot if in ggplot as `geom_bar`

Using the code below will give as plot, however It does not have right properties:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

mtcars %>% select(-cyl) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(mean_hp = mean(hp), 
            median_hp = median(hp), 
            count = n()) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value)) + geom_bar() + 
  facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you want to set both `x` and `y` aesthetics:

```
mtcars %>% select(-cyl) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(mean_hp = mean(hp), 
            median_hp = median(hp), 
            count = n()) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=key, y=value)) + geom_col()
```

Note that `geom_col` is better adapted in your case, as `geom_bar` is used for histograms (the height of the bar is proportional to the number of cases in each group).

You could still use faceting anyway but with only one plot per facet, the result will not be that pretty.

On second thought, it seems that your example makes little sense to me. Wouldn't this be more usefull?

```
mtcars %>% select(-cyl) %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  summarise(mean_hp = mean(hp), 
            median_hp = median(hp), 
            count = n()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols=c(mean_hp, median_hp)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=name, y=value, fill=factor(gear))) + 
    geom_col(position = "dodge")
```

(Also, try to use `pivot_longer` and `pivot_wider` instead of `gather` and `spread`, which are now deprecated)